# Converting BLOB data into Images

Tags: blackberry, blob

I have a sqlite .db file which consists of data in string, int and blob data types. The blob data consists of images. Can anyone tell me how to convert the blob data into images and then display in a list field. Any code snippets or tutorials will be of great help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert BLOB data into a `byte[] b` array. When you have that a simple call to 
`EncodedImage icon = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, -1);`
Will give you an image which you can later convert to bitmap with `icon.getBitmap();`